# Selecting all but the first child of parent with an ID and then applying action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select all the child elements of a parent element (except the first) with `jQuery` and I have the below..

```
$("li:not(:first-child)");
```

But I'm not sure how I can apply it to just the certain parent `ID`, would something like this work?

```
$('#myID').("li:not(:first-child)");
```

If so, I then want to add an element *before* the respective `<li>` tag. Would I then be able to do this with?

```
$('#myID').("li:not(:first-child)").before('<li>Test</li>');
```

I'm guessing something above is wrong as it isn't working.

Comment: Do you want to find all descendants of `#myID` which are not the first child of their respective parent or only the children of `#myID` except the first one?

Comment: Only wanted the children of #myID. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close, just pass in the selector context:

```
$("li:not(:first-child)", "#myID")
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

```
jQuery( selector [, context] )

selector: A string containing a selector expression

context: A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context
```

EDIT:
My initial answer assumed that you have no more li within the child's li. if you strictly only wants to select the children, use `>`:

```
$("#myID > li:not(:first-child)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple: using the `:gt()` <sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)</sup> selector:

Just do it like: **[demo fiddle](http://jsbin.com/iqahit/2/edit)**

```
$("#myID li:gt(0)").before('<li>Test</li>');
```

If you are concerned about speed :) :

```
$("#myID").find("li:gt(0)").before('<li>Test</li>');
```

or like: **[demo fiddle](http://jsbin.com/iqahit/1/edit)**

```
$("#myID li:not(:first-child)").before('<li>Test</li>');
```

Answer (score 1):

There's different solutions:

```
$("li:not(:first-child)", "#myID"); // see @SiGanteng answer

$("#myID li:not(:first-child)");

$("#myID").find("li:not(:first-child)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `#myID` is a `ul` or `ol` element, another possible way to get all children but the first is

```
$('#myID').children().slice(1)
```